# Through GUI get information from user and put them in JTable (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing

for example:

```
    JLabel l1, l2, l3;
    JTextField f1,f2,f3;
    JTable table;
    JButton b1,b2;

    l1 = new JLabel( "Name" );
    l2 = new JLabel( "age" );
    l3 = new JLabel( "sex" );

    f1 = new JTextField( 10 );
    f2 = new JTextField( 10 );
    f3 = new JTextField( 10 );

     b1 = new JButton( "Submit" );
     b2 = new JButton( "Next" );

    String[] column = {"Name","Age","Sex"};

    Object[][] data= {.....};
```

data is filled by user through the GUI,it proceeds as user clicks "Next" and stops till the user clicks "submit".(or you can give anther way of data insertion)

```
    table = new JTable(data,column);
```

Comment: What is your question? Your problem?

Comment: And what is your question exactly? What part do you have problems with?

Comment: I want to ask the user to enter data (Name,age,sex...etc) in the JTextField, then I want this data to be printed on screen through GUI in a form of a JTable.Then save into a file @EWit

Comment: I want to ask the user to enter data (Name,age,sex...etc) in the JTextField, then I want this data to be printed on screen through GUI in a form of a JTable.Then save into a file  @Thierry

Answer (score 1):

> data is filled by user through the GUI,it proceeds as user clicks "Next"

Well you can't use an Array to hold the data since you don't know how many time the user is going to click "Next" to get information.

So instead your code should create an empty table with just column headers:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then in the logic for the "Next" button you get the data from the from and then dynamically add the row of data to the table:

```
model.addRow(....);
```

The model will be updated and the model will notify the table to repaint itself.

Or if you want the table to only be updated when the "Submit" button is clicked then you would add the model to the table in the "Submit" logic.